# Proof involving eigenvectors/values of a linear map and polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, eigenfunctions

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $k$, and let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be linear, and let $f\in k[x]$. Suppose that $\lambda\in k$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ and let $v\in V$ be a corresponding eigenvector. Show that $f(T)v=f(\lambda)v$.

I'm not sure where to start. All I know is that $Tv=\lambda v$. I was thinking it might be easier to show that $f(T-\lambda I)=0$, but I still don't know where to start. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Since $Av=\lambda v$, what can you say about $A^2 v$? $A^3 v$?

Comment: Since f is a polynomial with coefficients in $k$, we can write $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i $ with $n = deg (f)$ and each $a_i$ in k. Along with the fact that $Tv=\lambda v $, this should give you the required equation.

Comment: Ok so:$\\$

$f(T)v=\sum_{i=0}^na_i(T)^iv\\$
$=a_0T^0v+a_1T^1v+a_2T^2v+\dots\\$
$=a_0\lambda^0v+a_1\lambda^1v+a_2\lambda Tv+\dots\\$
$=a_0\lambda^0v+a_1\lambda^1v+a_2\lambda^2v+\dots\\$
$=\sum_{i=0}^na_i\lambda^iv\\$
$=f(\lambda)v$

Is there a way I can write this while keeping summation notation, I don't really like the look of expanding out the summation...

Comment: You don't need to expand the sum, in particular not if you've shown that $\lambda^i v=T^i v $ beforehand.